# How to drop a subversion changelist

Tags: svn

The *changelist* feature of subversion is quite useful to distinct work related to different tasks in the same workspace.

```
svn changelist MyIssue fileA fileB
svn commit --cl MyIssue fileA
```

But after completing the work the *changelist* still contains all files, which are not committed (e.g. reverted).
 
`svn status` result in the following output:

> --- Changelist 'MyIssue':
>            fileB

This files have to be manually removed from the changelist.

As far as I know, the only way to remove this *changelist* in the current workspace is to invoke:

```
svn changelist --remove fileB
```

My questions concerning the *changelist* are:

- Is there an another way to drop the *changelist* in the current workspace?
- Are any convenience work-around e.g. shell script or emacs function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove a whole directory of files, use the `--recursive` flag with changelist

Following are the options in changelist

```
--changelist ARG
--depth ARG
--quiet (-q)
--recursive (-R)
--remove
--targets FILENAME
```

Comment: o.k. this is helpful if I want to drop all references below a distinct directory, e.g.: `svn changelist --remove --recursive --changlist MyIssue .`

Answer (score 0):

Never used changelists myself, but it sounds like I want to give it a try. So thanks for the hint.

Not a finished answer for you, but maybe a valuable starting point: I created a small shell wrapper for the svn cli command: http://cli-apps.org/content/show.php/crescow?content=147510

You could add another subcommand to perform a cleanup as you require. This would make it more convenient to use compared to a separate script or something. For example you could introduce the sub command 'cleanup', so that you can call '>svn cleanup MyIssue'

Drop a note if you succeed.